# How to replicate publish web site in c# code

Tags: c#

Task: I try to publish a web application with EnvDte dll's and the code bellow.

Problem: The publish fails because I need to specify the publishing location. But I don't know how to add this to my code.

Code:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.9.0", true);
DTE dte = (DTE)System.Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);
dte.MainWindow.Visible = true;

VsWebSite.VSWebPackage webPkg = dte.GetObject("WebPackage") as VsWebSite.VSWebPackage;
webPkg.OpenWebSite(path, VsWebSite.OpenWebsiteOptions.OpenWebsiteOption_None, true);

SolutionBuild2 slnbld2 = (SolutionBuild2)webPkg.DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild;

slnbld2.Clean(true);
slnbld2.Build(true);
slnbld2.Publish(true);
```